# multiple one-to-one relationship mysql

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, one-to-one

is it possible to create table with multiple one-to-one relationships?
I am tring to obtain it via below query but get SQL error.

Tables are:
Order:

- id
- cart id (1:1)
- user id (1:1)
- payment_method_id
- shipping_method_id
- total price

User

- id
- email
- phone
- first name
- last name
- address
- post code
- city
- password NULL

Cart:

- id
- cookie
- cartItem_id(1:many)
- grandTotal

I would like to create table Order with two columns having one-to-one association.

```
create table order
( id int auto_increment
, cart_id int
, user_id int
, payment_method_id int
, shipping_method_id int
, total_price int
, primary key(user_id)
, primary key(cart_id));
```

I copied the below query but I am getting error and don't know why.

```
create table order(id int auto_increment, cart_id int, user_id int, payment_method_id int, shipping_method_id int, total_price int, primary key(id), foreign key (user_id) references user(id), foreign key (cart_id) references cart(id));
```

it says:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near 'order(id int auto_increment, cart_id int, user_id int,
> payment_method_id int, sh' at line 1

What is it I cannot see? I only changed Id into id.

Comment: You can't have several primary keys, but you can declare one of them unique instead. Seems a bit odd that a user can only place one order though. You should reveal the exact error message

Comment: You can't have more than one Primary key on table

Comment: Thank you. Then order should be many to one with user. I think this is more reasonable as person should be able to place more than one order.  The error said nothing specific. It refers only to incorrect syntax. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You can't have more than one Primary key on a Table.
Secondly, To have a relation you need to use **Foreign Key**

Try below Query:

```
create table order
( id int auto_increment
  , cart_id int
  , user_id int
  , payment_method_id int
  , shipping_method_id int
  , total_price int
  , primary key(id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User(Id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (cart_id) REFERENCES Cart(Id));
```

Comment: Thank you Roshan. Is it then many to one relation?

Comment: @Tommeck37 Yes. One to Many relation ship

Comment: ok - it did not allow me to use table name 'order'. I changed to 'orders' and it is fine now thank you